# Android - reading a text file from Assets seems to include a LOT of junk before/after the actual data?

Tags: android, compression, assets, corruption, text-files

I package a text file with my Android App (in Assets) which I read within the App itself.

To avoid this file being compressed, it's named 'mytestfile.mp3' and until recently, that worked just fine.

In one of the recent SDK/ADT changes, it seems something 'odd' is happening when reading from Assets and I'm open to ideas as to what it is...

I use code something like this

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("mytextfile.mp3");
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor()));
String line = f.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    // do stuff
    Log.d("TAG",line);
}
```

What I'm now seeing from the Log is rather odd - if the file contained something like this

```
Fred
Barney
Wilma
```

I'm seeing huge amounts of nonsense like this in the log

```
��ߴ�!�c�W���6�f����m�>ߩ���'�����6�#6���l0��mp�
```

followed - eventually by my text content

```
Fred
Barney
Wilma
```

followed by another metric tonne of gibberish - some of which looks like this

```
����������4�u?'����������������������������������������res/drawable-mdpi/icon.pngPK��������|v?,������������'�����������������������������res/layout-land/dialog_color_picker.xmlPK��������|v?1�!�����t2�������������������������������classes.dexPK��������|v?թVڝ����5���������������������������������META-INF/MANIFEST.MFPK��������|v?�v������j���������������������������������META-INF/CERT.SFPK��������|v?W7@�]�������������������������������������META-INF/CERT.RSAPK������������������������
```

As you can see, that appears to be raw binary content from the APK (and nothing to do with the text file)??

Is this a recent packaging issue or am I missing something? I'm using ADT15 but I've not tried the recent upgrade just yet!?

p.s. I've upgraded to the latest SDK/ADT and this problem persists - obviously I'd like to escalate it with whoever is at fault (no idea if the problem is Eclipse/ADT/ANT or Android centered) and so I'll start a bounty for ideas...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `AssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()` is for your .apk and not the `mytextfile.mp3` file inside the .apk. To work with `AssetFileDescriptor` you need to take e.g. `AssetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset()` into account as well, which is the offset to the actual file i.e. `mytextfile.mp3` in your case.

But there's an easy solution to your problem. Use `AssetManager.open(String)` instead, which will give you an `InputStream` to the `mytextfile.mp3` file. Like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("mytextfile.mp3");
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
// ...
```

Comment: Spot on - absolutely and totally correct - many thanks indeed.

There are DOZENS of examples of reading assets using openFD() (on this site and many others) so hopefully this question will help-out others too - I'll award the bounty when the 24-hour timer expires :)

Comment: Well, actually I posted the exact same solution before him (and even got two upvotes), so I wonder why he  gets the bounty and not me?

Comment: 2 reasons really...

1 - he explained WHY I was getting the gibberish rather than just offering a alternative solution which works (didn't your teachers tell you to  "show your working" ;) )

2 - at the time I posted that comment - his was the only visible reply (yours is visible now but wasn't at the time I posted it)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse/ADT occasionally gets the resources corrupted. Try doing a project clean and rebuild to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Done that several times - still get all the gubbins before/after the actual file content.

I also tried renaming the file to .png which resulted in slightly different binary junk before/after the content!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my app. Try using [Apache Commons IO's](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) `FileUtils`.
This adds another 100kb to your apk, but make File handling much easier.
And if you store the file as `myfile.txt` instead of `.mp3`, does it give the same output?

And did you create the file with a Windows or Linux/Unix System? (And with what application?)

/edit: This works for me:

```
AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("mytextfile.mp3");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = f.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            // do stuff
            Log.d("TAG", line);
            line = f.readLine();
        }
```

Comment: Ah, I think there is a mistake, as Assets are not handled as a file, hang on, I will do some research (I have the same output as you do)