# Android FileNotFound Exception with a plist file that will be built in

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to open a file for an Android app I am making. I tested the code that opens this file on a regular Java project, and it opens fine. However when I use this code in an Android Java project I get an java.io.FileNotFoundException error.

```
File file = new File ("list.plist");
```

Now the list.plist file is in the parent directory of the project. This file will be included in the app as its the only one it will be using.

I guess I am used to Xcode where I can just place the file anywhere in the project and I can access it without a problem.

How am I supposed to structure this path?

Thanks :-)

I've used this but it also did not work.

`File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile(), "list.plist");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to ensure the file you are using is packaged within your app - such as in the assets directory.

Secondly, Android automatically compresses plist files based on the extension. As a workaround, change the extension to something Android will not compress. These extensions include:

```
".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif",
".wav", ".mp2", ".mp3", ".ogg", ".aac",
".mpg", ".mpeg", ".mid", ".midi", ".smf", ".jet",
".rtttl", ".imy", ".xmf", ".mp4", ".m4a",
".m4v", ".3gp", ".3gpp", ".3g2", ".3gpp2",
".amr", ".awb", ".wma", ".wmv"
```

(for full article, see [dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/))

Comment: From my experience, yes. The other option that might work (does for some assets) is reading in using AssetFileDescriptor, as done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220527/android-reading-a-text-file-from-assets-seems-to-include-a-lot-of-junk-before)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this file in the assets dir and not in the parent folder. Any files in the parent folder need not be packaged with the app. Moreover, the structure of your files on a phone is not the same as you see in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "res/raw" or "assets" directory to include a raw file in your Android project.
see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: so its getAbsoluteFile() + /assests/list.plist? Because that doesn't work

Comment: for Assets, Activity#getAssets() returns AssetManager instance where you can get file handler. or you can access file via R file if you put file in res/raw dir

Answer (score 0):

I added the list.plist to the assets folder and renamed it list.mp3 to avoid compression issues.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("list.mp3");
```

This successfully opened the file without problems, which now allows me to parse the inputStream.

Thanks to Phil for giving sending me in the right direction.